# Laravel Cannot Access Image Stored in assets Folder after Uploading in Server

Tags: image, storage, assets, laravel-9, liveserver

if i image upload on live server , then image does not store in assets folder in laravel 9.

my project in laravel 9. my assets folder in public_html directory.i want to image store in assets folder not public folder or storage folder. please help me.